# What is the return type of search-forward and likewise other search functions?

Tags: search, emacs

I am trying to write an interactive function that goes through directories to search for words or names and return the files that contain a valid search result. I was trying to write this in a very simple way, but the way I am checking for valid search results is by doing:

```
(point-min)
(if(search-forward thing-to-find)
 (do-thing))
```

Whenever I test this it just adds directories that have no valid results anyway. Do I have to write an algorithm for searching words myself? I just need some direction here.

Comment: emacs already has `grep`, `rgrep`, `rzgrep`, etc. functions, but you can read any functions documentation with `C-h f` (not to mention the many additional libraries interfacing with `ag`, `ripgrep`, etc). You can also use the interactive repl, `ielm`, or `C-:` to evaluate elisp to see the results for yourself, or trace functions with `edebug`

Comment: I've tried reading the documentation,, and it tells me nothing about the return type. Upon evaluating them and storing the what is returned to a variable it seems to return something only upon a successful search. Otherwise, it errors out and no value is returned, but for whatever reason an unsuccessful search does not result in a nil, but rather just nothing happens. With that said, what would be the appropriate way to do what the code is intending to do in the opening post?

Comment: if you want it to return nil when unsuccessful, then set the third argument (explained in the docs).  Successful searches set the `match-data` -- access the appropriate matches with `(match-string <n>)`.  The docs also tell you the point is set after the match and it is returned.

Comment: Note the line `(point-min)` simply returns the min point, whereas you probably want `(goto-char (point-min))`

Comment: @Rorschach: Please consider providing your comment as an answer. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried reading the documentation, and it tells me nothing about the return type.

Not true.  <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `search-forward` says:

> Set point to the end of the occurrence found, and **return point**.

Point is a character position in the buffer -- an integer.
See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `point`, and <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Point`.

What is unfortunately missing from the docstring for `search-forward` is explanation of the NOERROR argument, details of which you *can* find in the analogous `re-search-forward` docstring:

> The optional third argument NOERROR indicates how errors are handled
>     when the search fails.  If it is nil or omitted, emit an error; if
>     it is t, simply return nil and do nothing; if it is neither nil nor
>     t, move to the limit of search and return nil.

Hence these functions return an integer upon success or, upon failure, either return `nil` (if NOERROR is non-nil) or signal an error.

Please <kbd>M-x</kbd> `report-emacs-bug` to report the documentation issue with `search-forward`.

Comment: Note also that @Rorschach has explained what is probably your biggest problem, which is the fact that you're calling `(point-min)` without *doing anything* with the value it returns, when you most likely wanted to move point to that position before you started searching.